# Enabling link in yii

Tags: yii, authorization

My question is how to enable a particular link for multiple user class. Currently I am doing in the following way for one user class

in layouts/main.php

```
array('label'=>'Users', 'url'=>array('/user/index'), 
  'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('admin'))
```

But what if I want to allow another class called superadmin then how should I do it? 
I can't do it like this

```
array('label'=>'Users', 'url'=>array('/user/index'),
  'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('admin'),
  'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('superadmin'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot do it, because arrays cannot have duplicate keys. What you can do is to use `||` (or) on that:

```
array('label'=>'Users', 'url'=>array('/user/index'),
  'visible'=> Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('admin')
           || Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('superadmin'))
```